# Using _("divId") as an HTML selector in JavaScript not working as expected. How do I get this to work as intended?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, getelementbyid, selectors-api

```
(function(){
    var _ = function(a) {return new q(a);},
           q = function (a) {var b = (typeof a === 'string') ? document.querySelector(a) : a;this.c = b;return this;};  
        _.fn = q.prototype = {
        off: function(a, b) {if(this.c.addEventListener) {this.c.removeEventListener(a, b, false);}else if(this.c.attachEvent) {this.c.detachEvent('on'+a, b);};return this;},
        on: function(a, b) {if(this.c.addEventListener) {this.c.addEventListener(a, b, false);}else if(this.c.attachEvent) {this.c.attachEvent('on'+a, b);};  return this;},
        add: function(a) {this.c.innerHTML = a; return this;}
    };
        if(!window._) {window._=_;}
    })();
```

I found this code. It works sort of like a JQuery selector ($) if I put in _("nameOfDivId").

I found however, that if I try to do something like this:

```
var theId = "mainBody";
_(theId).getElementsByTagName("img");
```

I get an error: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined*

It seems like it's finding the HTML element, but it's not passing the ACTUAL HTML object to me.

I want to be able to use this code to simplify javascript selectors, but I need to be able to run common javascript functions on the actual HTML element as well. How can I get this to work? I feel like I'm missing an important piece to the puzzle on how to use this properly.

Comment: Why not just `document.querySelector("#mainBody").getElementsByTagName("img")`? Do you have to use that code?

Comment: If it is similar to jQuery, you are missing your selector type. In your case it's an ID so your would need _(#mainBody)

Comment: I don't have to use it, but I've been using it on other projects. It makes my code cleaner and more concise when it works. And for most purposes it seems to work. Only when I try to run certain functions on it like "getElementsByTagName" it seems to not work. I just want to understand why so I can either use it correctly, or give up on it if it's not possible.

Comment: OMG @Rafael you are amazing!! That is totally the problem. It's working now. On a side not I also found out that I actually need to do this: _("#theDivId").c.getElementsByTagName("img"). Apparently the "c" stores reference to the actual HTML object. Found that out through trial and error.

Comment: `.c` is such a random variable name, it's clearly causing issues (at the least readability issues). It's none of my business but I suggest you get rid of that code and actually use jQuery, or plain old JavaScript (if you don't care much about browser compatibility).